# Task Scheduler - Task Keeps Becoming Disabled

Tags: scheduled-tasks, windows-task-scheduler

I have a task that I entered into Windows Task Scheduler (I have Windows 8.1) set to run automatically on system log-on and to repeat every 5 minutes indefinitely; however, after every time it runs, it disables itself, so now I have to keep going back to it to re-enable it and run it manually. Does anyone know why it is doing this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm having this same problem in Windows 10. It just started within the last few weeks (on a task that was auto-running successfully before), and the task runs manually without any problems.
Sorry to revive such an old post - This is the only relevant hit I'm finding in an Internet search for the problem.

Answer (score 2):

This happens when the task cannot be ran. Check your Error Logs to find more information on what's happening. Most likely, your path to the exe is incorrect or your permissions aren't right. Always test your tasks manually to ensure that this doesn't happen in the future.

Comment: It doesn't come up with any error. The path was correct, and when I tested it, it ran like a charm. Each time the action is triggered (when I sign in to Windows, in this case), it becomes disabled. Does it perhaps just turn off when the action was successful? If so, it seems to me that it shouldn't be doing that. It's certainly painfully irritating in my opinion.

Comment: @jeff are you running the task with the highest permissions, or as the correct user currently logged in?  or an administrator?

Comment: A Tom's Hardware thread (https://forums.tomshardware.com/threads/scheduled-tasks-keep-disabling.3143959/) suggests the culprit may be Avast's Game Mode (now Do Not Disturb mode). See https://techdows.com/2017/03/disable-avast-game-mode.html

Answer (score 2):

This may not be everybody's issue, but Avast Antivirus software can disable tasks in Task Scheduler and does not re-enable them.

It is an issue with avast "Game Mode" which they recently renamed to "Do Not Disturb Mode". Try turning this feature off and see if all your tasks stay enabled.